# Typescript Declare Interface Type as another Interface Type

Tags: class, typescript, types, interface

I have an interface called person that has a property called address which has a type of AddressInterface which is an interface. Is it correct to have a property of another interface or should this be a class Address that implements the address interface?

PersonInterface

```
import {AddressInterface} from "./address.interface"

export interface PersonInterface{
    firstname:string;
    lastname:string;
    dob:string;
    address:AddressInterface;
    username:string;
    email:string;
}
```

AddressInterface

```
export interface AddressInterface{
    name:string;
    line1:string;
    line2:string;
    city:string;
    postalcode:string;
    region:string;
    country:string;
}
```

Comment: Yep, the former seems the better option, to me. That is, use `AddressInterface`.

Comment: Agreed, as typescript is a structurally typed language it is totally acceptable to do what you have done above. No need to implement it in a class unless it will also have methods

Answer (score 0):

I used testclass to  implement all the  properties of PersonInterface.I think this the best way to follow the structure.
This is the class struture

```
export class testclass implements PersonInterface {

    firstname = "firstname";
    lastname = "lastname";
    dob = "12-25-1999";
    address = {
        name: "name",
        line1: "line1",
        line2: "line2",
        city: "city",
        postalcode: "postalcode",
        region: "region",
        country: "country",
    };
    username = "username";
    email = "email";
}
```

Interface definition :-
 "interfaces fill the role of naming these types, and are a powerful way of defining contracts within your code as well as contracts with code outside of your project".